# F has a nonempty basis implies F is the direct sum of a family of infinite cyclic subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be an Abelian group. How to prove the statement in the title?

Comment: "nonempty" is unnecessary.

Comment: A friendly advice: [title should NOT be the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). Also, in order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $F$, for every $x\in F$, $x=a_{i_1}e_{i_1}+..+a_{i_x}e_{i_x}, i_1,...,i_x\in I, a_ii\in\mathbb{Z}$, this implies that $F=\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_i$.